# VS2013 coded ui test fails at playback when trying to click on sub menu items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

Im new to coded UI test and doesn’t have much of coding background.
Im trying to automate a desktop application using coded ui test (VS 2013).I record the actions and manually do the changes to the code to extend or override the values.

There is a submenu in the main menu that I want to click.Structure of the sub menus are as follows.

1. Home;
2. Customer;

   2.1 New customer

   ```
   2.1.1 Customer type 1
   2.1.1 Customer type 2
   ```

   2.2 Existing customers

I want to click on customer type 1.I recorderded the steps using coded ui test builder and generated the code.when I try to play back; seems the coded ui test is stucked at the menu level without moving forward to the sub menu.
It fails each time giving following error.

“
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'Menu'
Name:  ‘XXX’
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.”

All the submenus behave the same and all of those fails at playback.but menu items are identifying without any problem.

I went through the similar articles related to submenu item problem.But failed to find a solution.

Does any of you face similar type of problems?Please give me your suggestions to solve this problem.

Appreciate if somebody can guide me with this.

Thank you very much.

```
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public partial class UIMap
{

    /// <summary>
    /// NewCustomerType1
    /// </summary>
    public void NewCustomerType1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinMenu uICustomersMenu = this.UITestWindow1.UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar.UICustomersMenu;
        WinMenu uINewCustomerMenu = this.UIItemWindow.UICustomersMenu.UINewCustomerMenu;
        WinMenuItem uICustomerType1MenuItem = this.UIItemWindow1.UIDesktopClient.UICustomerType1MenuItem;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Customers' popup menu
        Mouse.Click(uICustomersMenu, new Point(57, 16));

        // Click 'NewCustomer' popup menu
        Mouse.Click(uINewCustomerMenu, new Point(58, 7));

        // Click 'CustomerType1' menu item
        Mouse.Click(uICustomerType1MenuItem, new Point(30, 6));
    }

    #region Properties
    public UITestWindow1 UITestWindow1
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUITestWindow1 == null))
            {
                this.mUITestWindow1 = new UITestWindow1();
            }
            return this.mUITestWindow1;
        }
    }

    public UIItemWindow UIItemWindow
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIItemWindow == null))
            {
                this.mUIItemWindow = new UIItemWindow();
            }
            return this.mUIItemWindow;
        }
    }

    public UIItemWindow1 UIItemWindow1
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIItemWindow1 == null))
            {
                this.mUIItemWindow1 = new UIItemWindow1();
            }
            return this.mUIItemWindow1;
        }
    }

    public UITestWindow1 UITestWindow1
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUITestWindow1 == null))
            {
                this.mUITestWindow1 = new UITestWindow1();
            }
            return this.mUITestWindow1;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UITestWindow1 mUITestWindow1;

    private UIItemWindow mUIItemWindow;

    private UIItemWindow1 mUIItemWindow1;

    private UITestWindow1 mUITestWindow1;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UITestWindow1 : WinWindow
{

    public UITestWindow1()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II";
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new XXX(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        this.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar == null))
            {
                this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar = new UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar(this);
            }
            return this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar : WinMenuBar
{

    public UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "MainMenu";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinMenu UICustomersMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUICustomersMenu == null))
            {
                this.mUICustomersMenu = new WinMenu(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUICustomersMenu.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "Customers";
                this.mUICustomersMenu.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUICustomersMenu;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinMenu mUICustomersMenu;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UIItemWindow : WinWindow
{

    public UIItemWindow()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Instance] = "4";
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UICustomersMenu UICustomersMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUICustomersMenu == null))
            {
                this.mUICustomersMenu = new UICustomersMenu(this);
            }
            return this.mUICustomersMenu;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UICustomersMenu mUICustomersMenu;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UICustomersMenu : WinMenu
{

    public UICustomersMenu(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "Customers";
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinMenu UICustomersAccountsMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUICustomersAccountsMenu == null))
            {
                this.mUICustomersAccountsMenu = new WinMenu(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUICustomersAccountsMenu.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "Customers Accounts";
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUICustomersAccountsMenu;
        }
    }

    public WinMenu UINewCustomerMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUINewCustomerMenu == null))
            {
                this.mUINewCustomerMenu = new WinMenu(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUINewCustomerMenu.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "NewCustomer";
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUINewCustomerMenu;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinMenu mUICustomersAccountsMenu;

    private WinMenu mUINewCustomerMenu;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UIItemWindow1 : WinWindow
{

    public UIItemWindow1()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UIDesktopClient UIDesktopClient
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIDesktopClient == null))
            {
                this.mUIDesktopClient = new UIDesktopClient(this);
            }
            return this.mUIDesktopClient;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UIDesktopClient mUIDesktopClient;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UIDesktopClient : WinClient
{

    public UIDesktopClient(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinMenuItem UICustomerType1MenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUICustomerType1MenuItem == null))
            {
                this.mUICustomerType1MenuItem = new WinMenuItem(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUICustomerType1MenuItem.SearchProperties[WinMenuItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "CustomerType1";
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUICustomerType1MenuItem;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinMenuItem mUICustomerType1MenuItem;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UITestWindow1 : WinWindow
{

    public UITestWindow1()
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II";
        this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        this.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar1 UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar == null))
            {
                this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar = new UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar1(this);
            }
            return this.mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar1 mUIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar;
    #endregion
}

[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.30501.0")]
public class UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar1 : WinMenuBar
{

    public UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar1(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
        base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "MainMenu";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II"); ;
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinMenu UICustomersMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUICustomersMenu == null))
            {
                this.mUICustomersMenu = new WinMenu(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUICustomersMenu.SearchProperties[WinMenu.PropertyNames.Name] = "Customers";
                this.mUICustomersMenu.WindowTitles.Add("XXX - Version 5       User : User1       Institution : II"); ;
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUICustomersMenu;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinMenu mUICustomersMenu;
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code from your .uitest file that identifies the customer type1 as well as the properties of the control as defined in your application (if it's wpf or html, what does the code for it look like?).  This will help us answer your question with more than a "This is how I generally do this type of operation" when it may not apply to your specific scenario.

Comment: Applogies for the late reply and than you very much for the quick response.
I have attached a part of the designer file where it identifies the customer type 1.I hope this will help you to understand my problem.
Thank you again.

Comment: Im unable to access the code under test,hence Im not in  situation to share that code with you.But I will try to generate a similar code and share it with you if it gives the same error.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the actual UI code, then you'll have to use the [Coded UI Test Builder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balagans/archive/2009/12/28/9941582.aspx) to discover searchable properties for the controls in question.  Based on your code, it appears that either `UIBarControl_MainMenuMenuBar` or `UICustomersMenu` is the control that's throwing the exception because the Window Title doesn't match in every instance.  Try commenting out the lines about `WindowTitle.Add`, as it could be dynamically set and wouldn't work if the field changes state, as if a new customer is selected, for example.

This is a big reason that using the record and playback feature of the Coded UI Test Builder is unreliable.  Your best bet will be to either edit the SearchProperties for each control you discover in your .uitest file or to manually add controls to the map.cs partial class of the .uitest file using code.